# How to get user input on size and fill the array from a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, user-input

I am relatively new to Java and am confused on why my code does not work properly. I am creating a calculator using methods and arrays. In my code, the getOperand method I provided below is supposed to first prompt the user for enough values to fill an array and then return they array. This is where I am confused. If i must go into the same method, to retrieve both the size of the array and fill the array from user input, am I setting the array up correctly? Is it possible to return both? Below I tried what I thought would work but, it does not seem to work. When I try to fill the array I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
if(selection == 1) {

    double operand1[] = getOperand("Please enter the values for the first array, with a space after each input", size);
    double operand2[] = getOperand("Please enter the values for the second array, with a space after each input", size);

    System.out.println(add(operand1, operand2));


public static double[] getOperand(String prompt, int size) {    
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the size for the array");
size = input.nextInt();

double operand[] = new double[size];
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {

    operand[size] = input.nextDouble();
}
                                                                            // creating new arrays

System.out.println(prompt);
return operand;
```

I do not have the other methods set up yet, I am first trying to learn how to get the user inputs to fill the array. I also am unfortunately unable to add any new methods since my methods are pre-defined for me. Here is a list of the methods.

```
public static double[] add(double[] operand1, double[] operand2)
public static double[] subtract(double[] operand1, double[] operand2)
public static double[] multiply(double[] operand1, double[] operand2)
public static double[] divide(double[] operand1, double[] operand2)
public static double[] dotProduct(double[] operand1, double[] operand2)
public static double[] random(double lowerlimit, double upperlimit, int size)
```

Comment: This doesn't make logical sense: `int size = getOperand("What size would you like the array", size);` why would you create a method that returns an array of double and use it to try to get an int result?

Comment: If you declare arrays in Java, please use `double[] operand`, not `double operand[]`. The first is considered standard, and using it improves readability for anyone familiar with Java.

Comment: Why didn't you include the add() function?

Answer (score 1):

First, be more precise with the question as it is quite hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish, you may give some more information on what kind of operation you are trying to achieve.

So if I understand it correctly, you are trying to get a size of the array, then get two numbers from the user (those to be added to the array) and then add them together.

```
int size = getOperand("What size would you like the array", size);
double operand1[] = getOperand("What would you like the first number to be", size);
double operand2[] = getOperand("What would you like the second number to be", size);
System.out.println(add(operand1, operand2));
```

Those lines do not make any sense , as you are asking the user to input a size of the array however your method returns array. Also in your `getOperand` anyway you are asking your user about the size. Therefore use your `getOperand` method as a function that creates for you a array. e.g.

```
public static double[] getOperand(String prompt) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(prompt);

        int size = input.nextInt();
        double operand[] = new double[size]; // creating new arrays

        return operand;
    }
```

(the order of your operations was wrong as you were taking the user input before actually asking the user the question.)

You should create another method that takes a double from the user e.g.

```
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(Message);
        return (input.nextDouble());

    }
```

This would help you with taking the numbers form the user and then put them in the right entries of the array.

Also `double operand1[] = getOperand("What would you like the first number to be", size);` does not make sense neither. This is because you are trying to take a number from the user but you are not trying to access the entries from the array and actually add them but you are trying to make another array? this does not make any logical sense. 
What you should of have done is to create an array, then put the numbers that the user inputs into the first and second entry (0 and 1). I will give you an example in pseudocode so you can code it yourself;

```
CREATE array NAME userNumber TYPE double = SIZE userInputForSize
usernumber ENTRY 0 = userInputDouble
usernumber ENTRY 1 = userInputDouble
DOUBLE result = SUM(usernumber ENTRY 0, usernumber ENTRY 1)
print("The sum of your numbers is" result)
```

If you will give more information I can help more.

Comment: If you declare arrays in Java, please use `double[] operand`, not `double operand[]`. The first is considered standard, and using it improves readability for anyone familiar with Java.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I am seeing here is

```
int size = getOperand("What size would you like the array", size);
```

Your `getOperand` method is supposed to return a `double[]`. However, you are storing it in the size variable which is of type int.

The next problem that arises is that the second parameter of your getOperand method is `int size`. However you in your fix you changed `int size` to `double[] size`. I am unsure what exactly your code is trying to accomplish which is why I can't give an implementation.

Hope this helps.